# ProgressBar in ConstraintLayout not showing

Tags: java, android

I have a progressBar which should show on button click in `constraintlayout` which is not working, I have `newslist` activity which extends `baseActivity` which extends `appCompatActivity`

//////NewsListActivity

```
public class NewsListActivity extends BaseActivity {
    Button buttonTesting;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_list);

        buttonTesting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
        buttonTesting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (progressBar.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    showProgressBar(false);
                else
                    showProgressBar(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

//////BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null) ;
        FrameLayout frameLayout = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
        progressBar = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,frameLayout,true);
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility){
        progressBar.setVisibility(visibility? View.VISIBLE:View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

///////layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
        ></FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have a progressBar which should show on button click in `constraintLayout` which is not working, I have newslist activity which extends `baseActivity` which extends `appCompatActivity`

Comment: `<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
`

Comment: i did it but is not working

Comment: Remove constraint bottomtobottomof from progressbar. Also, what is the need of Framelayout their, it has no child in the XML itself. Set set of FrameLayout to wrapcontent

Comment: Where did u call ```public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility){
        progressBar.setVisibility(visibility? View.VISIBLE:View.INVISIBLE);
    }```??

Comment: @DebarshiBhattacharjee in NewsListActivity

Answer (score 3):

exchange this

```
super.setContentView(layoutResID);
```

to this

```
super.setContentView(constraintLayout);
```

you are inflating new `View` (`constraintLayout`), taking `progressBar` from it, but NOT setting this whole `View` as a content `View`, instead still calls `super.setContentView(layoutResID)`. so there is no `ConstraintLayout`, no frame and no progress bar, just inflating strigthly given layout resource. your `progressBar` is in memory (as inflated and tied to `Context`), so `showProgressBar` doesn't throw NPE, but also it still isn't added to `Activity`, so it's not visibile no matter of `visibility` attr

Comment: I'm thinking the OP and I are both following the same course by @mitch. I had the same problem. If anyone else runs into this, this answer did it for me! Thanks a ton. After rewatching the video, I noticed he didn't explicitly show it when he changed it, but later as he's switching between tabs, he has already made the change.